# Get height of newly appended li

Tags: jquery, height, append

How can I get the `.height()` of the newly appended li?

```
$("#siri").bind('webkitspeechchange', function() {
  var speech = $(this).val();
  $('ul').append("<li>' + speech + '</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating the element before?

```
var $li = $("<li>' + speech + '</li>");
$('ul').append($li);
var height = $li.height();
```

I think this should work ok...

Answer (score 0):

Is there some kind of unique identifier you can give to each newly appended li?

For example:

```
$("#siri").bind('webkitspeechchange', function() {
  var speech = $(this).val();
  $("ul").append("<li id='unique-id'>" + speech + "</li>");
  var itemHeight = $("#unique-id").height();
});
```